Can't view repopulated value or text for dropdownlist using DevExtreme selectBox
I think I managed to clear and existing data in dropdownlist / selectBox using DevExtreme. But when I click the dropdownlist / selectBox, I can see 5 options there but they are all empty.

When I want to troubleshoot it, I also could not able to.

       const prioritySelectBox = $('#PriorityValue').dxSelectBox("instance");

        const currentOptions = prioritySelectBox.option("dataSource");

        console.log("Current options:");
        currentOptions.forEach(option => {
            console.log("Value:", option.value, "Text:", option.text);
        });

        // Clear existing options
        prioritySelectBox.option('value', null);
        prioritySelectBox.option('dataSource', []); // Clear the data source

        // Create and insert new options based on ChildTargetingIds
        let newOptions = [];
        targetingTargetings.forEach(targeting => {
            targeting.TargetingTargetings.forEach(tt => {
                if (tt.TargetingTargeting.ParentTargetingId.toString() === targetingIds) {
                    newOptions.push({
                        value: tt.TargetingTargeting.ChildTargetingId,
                        text: 'test'
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        // Set the new options
        prioritySelectBox.option("dataSource", newOptions);
        console.log(prioritySelectBox.option());

        // Repaint the SelectBox to reflect changes
        prioritySelectBox.repaint();
        console.log(prioritySelectBox.option().dataSource);
        

